# if else cuando se loguea un usuario específico

Tags: php, login, condiciones, else

Tengo este código y necesito que en el `if` cuando se loguea el usuario "15" me muestre una tabla, y si se loguea otro usuario me muestre la tabla del `else`:

```html
<? 
require('./config/include.php');

$conexion = new accesoBDLocal(SERVIDORBD,USUARIOBD,CLAVEBD);
$conexion->SeleccionBD(BASEDATOS);

FuncionesPHPLocal::CargarConstantes($conexion,array("roles"=>"si","sistema"=>SISTEMA));
$conexion->SetearAdmiGeneral(ADMISITE);

$sesion = new Sesion($conexion,false);
$sesion->TienePermisos($conexion,$_SESSION['usuariocod'],$_SESSION['rolcod'],$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$oSistemaBloqueo = new SistemaBloqueo();
$oSistemaBloqueo->VerificarBloqueo($conexion); 

$oTorneos = new cTorneos($conexion);
$cCampeonatos = new cCampeonatos($conexion);
$oPartidos= new cPartidos($conexion);
if(!$oPartidos->BuscarEstadosPartidos($resultadoestadores,$numfilas))
    return false;
    
$_SESSION["resultados"]["fechaactual"] = $_POST["partidonumerofecha"] ;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modulos/dep_deportes/js/partidosresultados.js"></script>
<link href="modulos/dep_deportes/css/dep_partidos.css?v=1.3" rel="stylesheet" title="style" media="all"></link>
<?
$datos = $_POST;

$oPartidos->BuscarResultadosPartidosxZonacod($datos,$resultado,$numfilas);

if($numfilas>0){
?>

<div class="clearboth aire">&nbsp;</div>

<?
 if ($usuariocod == '15') {?>

<table class="TablaResultados">
    <tr border="1">
        <th style="width: 40%;">Equipo Local</th>
        <th style="width: 40%;">Equipo Visitante</th>
        <th style="width: 20%;">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</table>
     
<? }else{ ?>

<table class="TablaResultados">
    <tr border="1">
        <th style="width: 5%;">Cod</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Equipo Local</th>
        <th style="width: 6%;">Ptos. L.</th>
        <th style="width: 8%;">P Bonus L.</th>
        <th style="width: 6%;">Ptos. V.</th>
        <th style="width: 8%;">P Bonus V.</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Equipo Visitante</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;">Estado</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Fecha</th>
        <th style="width: 8%;">Hora</th>
        <th style="width: 20%;">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<? } ?>

</form>
<? }else{ ?> 
      <div class="nofixture"> El torneo seleccionado no tiene fixture cargado. </div>
<? } ?>
```

No me está mostrando el cambio de tabla.
Si alguno me podría dar una mano de como llamar al usuario logueado, le agradeceré mucho.
MIl gracias!
Saludos cordiales.-

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Donde esta definido $usuariocod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que se ve en el código `$usuariocod`  no está definido, deberías inicializarlo

```
$usuariocod = $_SESSION['usuariocod'];
```

o

hacer el if con la session directamente

```
if($_SESSION['usuariocod'] == 15) { Tabla1 }else { tabla 2}
```

Comment: Soy un tonto! Cómo no me dí cuenta de eso! Mil gracias!